# MVC Form Action URL being set incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing my first MVC app and I'm already having an issue with BeginForm.  When I test the project locally, the login form action is being set (correctly) to

`<form action="/Account/Login"`

When I publish it to the actual site, it is inexplicably prepending the application name to the action so it looks like this

`<form action="/appName/Account/Login"`

so when you try to actually login, the routing tables don't know where to post the request and nothing happens when you press Submit. Is there a way I can override this behavior?

Login.cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
 {
............ form
  }
```

RoutConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Show the code that generates this form.

Comment: Are you hosting it in a virtual directory?

Comment: no, it's an actual IIS application. should I use a virtual directory instead?

Comment: no, I can't use a virtual directory because I need the web config to work within the sub folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. If you hosted your application as a virtual directory or application under a website in IIS it is perfectly normal that the ASP.NET MVC helpers such as Html.BeginForm are taking this application name into account. So the `/appname` prefix you are seeing represent the application name in IIS under the website. You can have multiple ASP.NET MVC applications hosted under a single website and as you can see the ASP.NET MVC helpers are correctly taking them into account.

If on the other hand you host your application in IIS directly as a WebSite, without creating any sub-applications, the url helpers will take that into account and generate `action="/Account/Login"`.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but how do I get it working?  Do I have to add a new routing table entry with the application name hardcoded?

Comment: You already got it working correctly. If you don't want to see the application name in front of your urls you will need to setup your ASP.NET MVC application directly under the root WebSite in IIS. Or use a reverse proxy in front of IIS such as HAProxy or nginx that will do URL rewrites and remove the application name.

Comment: But when you press Submit on the login form, nothing happens!

Comment: Well that's an entirely different problem now that I very highly doubt has anything to do with your routes. Can you see the actual POST request being made in Fiddler?

Comment: but it works when you debug locally.  The only reason I can think of as to why it doesn't work when published is the form action URL.  It's behaving as though it never hits the AccountController

Comment: No, it's not the form action URL. It's something else. What's the actual payload of the HTTP POST request when you submit the form? What does the server responds with? can you provide a Fiddler capture of what happens under the covers? Also do you have some javascript that might be interfering and hijacking the actual form POST? Something like AJAX or something where you mihght have hardcoded some url in your javascript file instead of using an URL helper?

Comment: oh WTF, it's working now for no discernible reason.  You must have used your juju on it from afar.